# set conditional focus on some field in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hello all fellow engineers , i have seen so many questions and well suggesting answers regarding setting focus on some input field but i didn't found anything which will fulfill my requirements , now my question is if we have multiple input fields and we don't know where to set the focus , and on some condition basis i  want to set focus on some field back from controller, is there anything like "document.getElementbyId("").focus" as in javascript with "ng-model" or something , any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 5):

This directive will cause an element to receive focus when the passed in expression is truthy.

### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/geyen/1/edit)

Usage:

```
<!-- set `$scope.foo` to a truthy value when this input should be focused -->
<input type="text" focus-when="foo">
<button ng-click="foo = true">Focus input.</button>
```

The directive:

```
.directive('focusWhen', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      focusWhen: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {

      $scope.$watch('focusWhen', function(shouldFocus) {
        if (shouldFocus) {
          $element[0].focus();
        }
      });

    }
  };
})
```

Comment: the given demo is appreciated but the text box is getting focused on some event of button , i cannot use directive because i have so many text fields the most important thing if i want to focus on some field based on some condition from controller below is the code

Comment: @irfanshafi what this directive does is exactly that - it lets you focus the input based on a condition (expression) from the controller. Perhaps you don't understand what the button is doing?

Comment: function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.keylog = [];
    $scope.keyCount= 0;
    var len;
    
    $scope.handleKeypress = function(key) {
        $scope.keylog.push(key);
        if($scope.keylog[len-1]==17 && $scope.keylog[len]==13)
         $scope.addUser();
          len=$scope.keylog.length;
          
    };
}

Comment: after calling the function "adduser()", i want to focus on some text field

Comment: @irfanshafi yes, please examine my answer more carefully. Assuming you passed in `foo` to the directive, then set `$scope.foo = true` in the controller and the input will be focused. That's the same thing the button is doing in my example.

Comment: To prevent fail on many navigators, you should to use $timeout to call the .focus() function.

Comment: @irfanshafi hi bro, i have seen something like it in a validation of forms.will that be helpful?